# How to protect (or lock) Apache Server folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows, apache, windows-7

I am running **PHP 5** and **MySQL** with **Apache 2** in my **Windows 7 PC**. Everything (in localhost) is working fine and the localhost is defined in port 80 (It works!). But I would like to password protect (or lock) and hide server folder including htdocs. I mean, I don't want want another user to access the server folder and files. I know that I can remove installation information from add/remove programs menu by removing registry entries (hope it won't affect the server framework). But how can I prevent the users from accessing the server folder? The server folder is a master folder, in which I installed Apache, PHP and MySQL. I made it in C: drive(to ensure security). I want to lock the master folder (password protected). Only I should have the access to them (my friends use my PC). But the content (localhost) should be delivered (I mean the pages should come, along with PHP and MySQL) for everyone. Only a single user account is there (Admin).

How can I lock and hide my folder while running server silent/hidden. Is this possible with or without any software?

Comment: Is there another suitable title for the question?

Comment: why close? The question is genuine.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.devside.net/articles/windows/password

http://www.brandx.net/support/buildingwebsites/passwords.shtml

http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml

Implement User/Password-protected Directories for Apache Server